# Sass::SyntaxError: Alpha channel 8 must be between 0 and 1 for `rgba'

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, saas

I am expecting an error in my **style.css** file.

Tried all the possible options but it did'nt help so far.

The link to css file is: [Link to my style.css since I am not posting file here](http://www.writeurl.com/text/fyzfujzce7k6kerpztyc/zg7ymgofzxcbnjvl3n5q)

When I pre-compile my assets using:

`rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

it returns error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Alpha channel 8 must be between 0 and 1 for `rgba'
```

P.S: The CSS file may take few seconds to load for showing you file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a search through your code and found on the 380th, 382nd and 384th out of 437 instances of `rgba(` you have a css class somewhere in your structure as follows:

```
/**/
/* checked state */
/**/

.radio input + i:after {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 8);
}
...
.checkbox input + i:after {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 8);
}
...
.radio input:checked + i,
.checkbox input:checked + i,
.toggle input:checked + i {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 8);
}
```

The three **8**s should be **0.8**s or something similar to fix the issue.